# Sending onion messages with c-lightning

Tags: lightning-network, core-lightning

I have a simulated network of 3 CLightning nodes, A,B, and C.
I want to use the sendonionmessage command to send a message from A to C going through B and then the response coming back to A through B.
I don't know what values I should use for the command's arguments and how to build the blinding argument.

```
lightning-cli sendonionmessage <first_id> <blinding> <hops>
```

My question is how can I create the right arguments for this command?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, this is a little bit complicated, I think you can write a plugin to simplify this procedure by looking at the code of `fetchinvoice`.

We have an open issue https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning/issues/6578